eso-pic background image different on first page when not knowing where pages break
Trying to put a background image on a document where the first page background image is different using eso-pic, but not getting what I think the documentation implies.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pageX.pdf}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{page1.pdf}}

\begin{document}

page 1
\eject 
page 2
\eject 
page 3  
\end{document}

The above ends up putting the pageX image on all three pages.  In the real document I won't know where the pages break so can't do something like the below which does works as anticipated.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, eso-pic}


\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{page1.pdf}}
page 1
\eject 
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pageX.pdf}}
page 2
\eject 
page 3  
\end{document}

Various reordering of the \AddToShipoutPictureBG also don't seem to work, only having an \eject in between them.

In eso-pic the hook for the starred version is always behind the normal hook. But you can use the LaTeX-hooks instead. There the order is the other way round
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-A}}}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}}

\begin{document}

page 1
\eject 
page 2
\eject 
page 3  
\end{document}

or use a test for the page number:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,-\paperheight)
 {\ifnum\value{page}=1 
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}%
  \else
   \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-A}%
  \fi  }}

\begin{document}

page 1
\eject 
page 2
\eject 
page 3  
\end{document}


Thank you.  First one did not work for me (with the LaTeX hooks), giving the first image on all pages.  Second solution did though.

hm, the first should work fine (it does for me, I did test that). Do you have a current tex system?

Yes, TexLive 2024. Building with luatlatex or pdflatex gave same results for me. Also I'm seeing the image in the foreground and can't typeset on top of it.

hm, did you use exactly my code or did you change it?

changed to my files, otherwise cut and paste

Using simple rectangles as images made both approaches work and both approaches in background as intended.  Perhaps there is something in the z-order / layers in my images making things strange.  I'll figure it out.

To those who might be coming to this question.  Also note that using the textpos package in absolute mode. (i.e. \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}) affects the shipout hook. That textpos[absolute] can interact with other packages is described in the notes section of the package documentation V 1.10.1.  In the case here it wrote text behind the actual background picture shipped out.
